# 'No such file or directory' whilst the directory already exists. (c)

Tags: c

Whilst trying to compile my C project with GCC, I keep getting an error that goes something like this:

```sh
main.c:2:10: fatal error: ./include/windows.h: No such file or directory
 #include <./include/windows.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What confuses me most is that the 'include' directory already exists.
If anyone has encountered a similar problem and knows how to fix the error that'd be great,  thanks :)

Comment: Remove the `./include/` part?

Comment: @anastaciu By removing that I would get an error because windows.h is stored in that directory.

Comment: If it's a header created by you you should use "" guards instead of <>. If the file is not found that means the path is wrong.